# Failed to compact generated WASM binary in substrate standalone chain

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, wasm, evm

I'm building the substrate standalone chain with this `cargo build --release` command  and facing the issue:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to compact generated WASM binary.: Error(UnknownOpcode(192))', /Users/asadali/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/a3ed011/utils/wasm-builder/src/wasm_project.rs:673:14
 note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: It was just because of your rust version issue. Kindly downgrade the nightly version.